# Get Euro currency while travelling from India

Tags: europe, india, money, airports, exchange

I'll be travelling to Europe from India in a few days.

While I have got some currency (Euro) from the Indian bank, I just wanted to ask if I can purchase some Euro (against Indian Rupee) from the airport at India while leaving.
If yes, is there any minimum Euro amount that I need to purchase for?

Also for the forex I have got from the bank, the bank has given me a Sales invoice. Is that enough and the only thing I need to show at the airport for the forex ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can purchase **Euros** against your **Indian ruppee** at the international airport you'll be departing from. All international airports in India have **Forex** services.

Usually, as far as Government regulations is concerned, there is no minimum amount which you have to exchanged, but that depends on the discretion of the service provider. There is however, a maximum limitation applicable as per Government regulations (in Indian context, **Foreign Exchange Management Act, 1999**)

Delhi International Airport has two service providers for Forex services - **Central Bank of India** and **Thomas Cook**.

Mumbai International Airport has the following service providers in International departure terminal:

- Centrum
- Travelex
- Central Bank of India
- Akbar Travels
- Thomas Cook

Comment: Thx a lot for the details...For the Sales invoice, could you please help me understand the same...I have got the sales invoice for around 1250 Euros (Cash+Travel card) from ICICI bank...Is that enough and needs to be shown at the airport ?

Comment: Yes, that is enough in case you are asked by customs to show the forex you're carrying and the receipt. Though, that is a highly improbable event for normal travelers.